# How to unhide a button on another button click which selects file using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a button, which will be disabled by default. I have another button which is used to select a file. Now on selecting the file I want to enable the previous button. How can we do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Base64 Upload Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/adonespitogo/angular-base64-upload/master/src/angular-base64-upload.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
  </script>
  <style>
    body{padding-bottom: 50px;}
    .alert{margin-top: 15px;}
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="container">
    <form name="form">
    <h3>Single File Selection</h3>
      <div class="input-group">
        <label for="file">Select File</label>
        <input type="file" ng-model="upload" name="file" base-sixty-four-input required onload="onLoad" maxsize="500" accept="image/*">

      </div>
      <button class="col-lg col-lg btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="upload" ng-click="$ctrl.uploadDocument()">Upload</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/xhLtvqSdZqO8bGwpoVa7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this directive: https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload.

It will let you build an upload button that easily integrates with angular, like so:

```
<button type="file" ngf-select="onLoad($file, $invalidFiles)"
          accept="image/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="1MB">
      Select File
</button>
```

That directive takes a little bit to get used to, but will ultimately make your life easier.

This will access your $scope.onload file and provide it with a file object with data about the file you're uploading.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the state of variable upload when calling onLoad function.

```
 $scope.upload = false;
```

Also don't forget to initialize value of $scope.upload inside controller (set it to true).

You could even replace this $scope.upload by controller method.

Comment: I tried onLoad but dont know why its not working...Can u have a look at this plucker once

https://plnkr.co/edit/nrfxij9c808ENLZy6p0U?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any on change or on load listener functions. Just do `ng-disabled="!upload"`. It'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [the example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled#example) from the documentation for [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) below. Notice how the *ng-disabled* attribute of the button is set to **checked**, which is the same value as the attribute *ng-model* of the checkbox.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <label>Click me to toggle <i>disabled</i> on the button:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked">
  </label>
  <br/>
  <button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
</div>
```

With your snippet, there is just one (mostly) small difference - the input is a *file* input instead of a checkbox. 
Because the file input is bound to *upload* (via `ng-model="upload"`) the (negated) value can be used to set [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled), since it will initially be [*falsey*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and then when a file is selected, it will be the opposite (I.e. [*truthy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)), which will set **disabled** to *false* for the second buttton.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <label for="file">Select File</label>
    <input type="file" ng-model="upload" name="file" base-sixty-four-input required onload="onLoad" maxsize="500" accept="image/*">   
</div>
<button class="col-lg col-lg btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!upload" ng-click="uploadDocument()">Upload</button>
```

See it in action in [this forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zdsY7HUaIFhGAP80xsTv?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like in your controller and template code. I had made some changes

Template

```
<button class="col-lg col-lg btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!isFileSelected" ng-click="$ctrl.uploadDocument()">Upload</button>
```

Controller

```
angular.module('myApp', ['naif.base64'])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope, $http, $window, $rootScope){

  $scope.isFileSelected = false;

  $scope.onChange = function (e, fileList) {
    alert('this is on-change handler!');
  };

  $scope.onLoad = function (e, reader, file, fileList, fileOjects, fileObj) {
    alert('this is handler for file reader onload event!');
    $scope.isFileSelected = true;
  };

  var uploadedCount = 0;

  $scope.files = [];
})
```